# USE IONIC STORAGE DATA ON ANOTHER FUNCTION

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Am using ionic to develop a new APP.

i have have a service lool like this

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
//No problem on import

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class myservice {

  serverUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  httpHeader = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
  };

  userid: number;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private storage: Storage) {
  }

  async getFromStorageAsync(){
      await this.storage.get('userid').then((val)=>{
        this.userid = val;
        console.log("UserId", this.userid); //Here it work fine
      });
      console.log("UserId", this.userid); // Here it work fine too
  }

  use_storage_data() {
    this.getFromStorageAsync();
    console.log("Userid",this.userid); // Here is undefined
    let postData = {
      userid: this.userid, // here is undefined
      username: "samplename"
    };
    return this.http
      .post<any>(this.serverUrl + "/appdata.php", postData)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

}
```

Then on page i call it like this

```
  getData(){
    this.myservice.use_storage_data().subscribe(data => {
     // console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Please help me to make storage data as global variable
Or you may suggest a new approach to save and use data like user id and user name on ionic app

NOTE i have successful set userid when user login

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the way i get value from storage

On page i import this

```
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
```

Get value from storage and pass to service

```
  getData(){
    this.storage.get('userid').then((val)=>{
      this.myservice.use_storage_data(val).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

This work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

you are dealing with Future there hence at the very first call, userId is undefined because the method is Asynchronous, i.e it operates behind the scenes while other processes keep on going...

The value of the userId variable will get updated somewhere in the future and hence to tackle this in your program, you have to add a .then thing in your method such that whenever a value is got from an asynchronous method, your variable userId gets updated..

To show you the code....

```js
use_storage_data() {
    this.getFromStorageAsync().then(val => console.log(val)); //here it will be defined
    // what you could do now:
    this.getFromStorageAsync().then((id){
      console.log("Userid", id); // defined
    if(id){
    // to ensure that the first undefined value(if any) of id is not captured
    let postData = {
      userid: this.userid, // here is undefined
      username: "samplename"
    };
    return this.http
      .post<any>(this.serverUrl + "/appdata.php", postData)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    });
    }
    
  }
```

Hope that helps